# Pandas Installation Using Pip and Easy_install

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a problem with my pandas. First I tried easy-install on cd C:\Python27\Scrips...doing. `easy_install.exe numpy`, and `easy_install.exe pandas`but only the numpy worked, the pandas didnt, so I used pip to install. and it worked on both. But going back to my code, when I tested it,

heres my code:

```
import fileinput
import csv
import numpy
import pandas
#records = pe.iget_records(file_name="test.xlxs")
records = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, nrows=5)

#To Write ni





cho = raw_input("\nStart Forecaster on file?:<1/0>")

if cho == 1:

  for record in records:
     rem = df.iloc([i], [0])
     print(rem)
     sold1 = df.iloc([i], [1])
     print(sold1)
     sold2 = df.iloc([i], [2])
     print(sold2)

     rem = int(rem)
     sold1 = int(sold1)
     sold2 = int(sold2)

     result = forecast(rem,sold1,sold2)
     print(result)
     df.set_value([i], [4], result)
     pd.to_csv('test.csv')
  print "Forecast Complete! Please check the file!"


else:
  quit()
```

But i get this error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "tester.py", line 4, in <module>
        import pandas
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
        from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
      File "pandas\src\numpy.pxd", line 157, in init pandas.hashtable (pandas\hashtable.c:40866)
    ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 52, got 56
```

Comment: You should delete them both and reuse pip to install them

Comment: ummm.. do you mean the  easy_install ones?

Comment: Nah, why don't you just delete all pandas and numpy and use pip to install them again once

Comment: it worked bruh @abcd thanks bruh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to remove all previous installations of `pandas` and `numpy` because you installed them successively too many times making the libraries confused. After deleting them, reinstall `pandas` and `numpy` by using `pip`, like so:

```
pip install numpy
pip install pandas
```